# How to Undo installation settings

Tags: server, samba

Recently I just installed ubuntu server 14.0.4 and I was able to install active directory domain controller with samba, but i realized there some issues i'll ran into when connecting the client computers to this domain. How do I unistall all these settings I have already made so far to my server and start again from the scratch installing only ubuntu file server with samba?

Thanks

Comment: Will removing packages work for you?

Comment: I think so....if i get the correct commands to remove evrything I have already installed and set it up with file server and samba...

Comment: apt-get remove --purge package

Comment: unable to locate package. That's the message i got after running that command

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge package_name
```

Comment: the name will be my domain name right?

Comment: suppose i want to complete reformat the whole system and start new installation should i just plug in the CD and follow the normal steps or there are commands to do so along with the installation CD?

Comment: Do you mean you want to undo the settings or remove the packages?

If you want to reinstall, than you can just put the CD and follow the normal installation